# How can I use seaborn without changing the matplotlib defaults?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use seaborn, because of its distplot function. But I prefer the default matplotlib settings. When I import seaborn, it changes automatically the appearance of my figure.

How can I use seaborn functions without changing the look of the plots?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Version 0.8 (july 2017) changed this behaviour. From https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017:

> The default (seaborn) style is no longer applied when seaborn is
> imported. It is now necessary to explicitly call set() or one or more
> of set_style(), set_context(), and set_palette(). Correspondingly, the
> seaborn.apionly module has been deprecated.

For older versions, Import seaborn like this:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
```

and then you should be able to use `sns.distplot` but maintain the default matplotlib styling + your personal rc configuration.

Answer (score 23):

According to documentation [`reset_orig`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.reset_orig.html)  restore all RC params to original settings:

```
import seaborn as sns
# reset RC params to original
sns.reset_orig()
```

Comment: This is the better answer as it does not trigger a deprecation warning on newer versions of the library.