# Seaborn configuration hides default matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html) provides of a handful of graphics which are very interesting for scientifical data representation.
Thus I started using these Seaborn graphics interspersed with other customized matplotlib plots.
The problem is that once I do:

```
import seaborn as sb
```

This import seems to set the graphic parameters for seaborn globally and then all matplotlib graphics below the import get the seaborn parameters (they get a grey background, linewithd changes, etc, etc).

In SO there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393936/how-can-i-use-seaborn-without-changing-the-matplotlib-defaults) explaining how to produce seaborn plots with matplotlib configuration, but what I want is to keep the matplotlib configuration parameters unaltered when using both libraries together and at the same time be able to produce, when needed, original seaborn plots.

Comment: The seaborn documentation is quite good. This is covered near the beginning of the installation docs: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/installing.html?highlight=apionly#importing-seaborn

Comment: I'm not certain this is an exact duplicate of that question: it also addresses the need to switch between seaborn and matplotlib defaults dynamically in a script, which is not covered in the suggested duplicate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [seaborn version 0.8 (July 2017)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017) the graph style is not altered anymore on import:

> The default [seaborn] style is no longer applied when seaborn is imported. It is now necessary to explicitly call **`set()`** or one or more of **`set_style()`**, **`set_context()`**, and **`set_palette()`**. Correspondingly, the `seaborn.apionly` module has been deprecated.

You can choose the style of any plot with `plt.style.use()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn')     # switch to seaborn style
# plot code
# ...

plt.style.use('default')     # switches back to matplotlib style
# plot code
# ...


# to see all available styles
print(plt.style.available)
```

Read more about [`plt.style()`](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

Comment: I had to do `plt.style.use('classic')` to get the default matplotlib style.

Comment: Yes, good point. `plt.style.use('classic')` changes to the old matplotlib `1.X` default style  `plt.style.use(default)` is the `2.X` new default.  Check https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html to see the changes in depth.

Comment: how can I see which style is currently used?

Answer (score 23):

If you never want to use the `seaborn` style, but do want some of the seaborn functions, you can import seaborn using this following line ([documentation](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/whatsnew.html#using-the-package)):

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
```

If you want to produce some plots with the `seaborn` style and some without, in the same script, you can turn the `seaborn` style off using the [`seaborn.reset_orig`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.reset_orig.html) function.

It seems that doing the `apionly` import essentially sets `reset_orig` automatically on import, so its up to you which is most useful in your use case.

Here's an example of switching between `matplotlib` defaults and `seaborn`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

# a simple plot function we can reuse (taken from the seaborn tutorial)
def sinplot(flip=1):
    x = np.linspace(0, 14, 100)
    for i in range(1, 7):
        plt.plot(x, np.sin(x + i * .5) * (7 - i) * flip)

sinplot()

# this will have the matplotlib defaults
plt.savefig('seaborn-off.png')
plt.clf()

# now import seaborn
import seaborn as sns

sinplot()

# this will have the seaborn style
plt.savefig('seaborn-on.png')
plt.clf()

# reset rc params to defaults
sns.reset_orig()

sinplot()

# this should look the same as the first plot (seaborn-off.png)
plt.savefig('seaborn-offagain.png')
```

which produces the following three plots:

`seaborn-off.png:`
[image: seaborn-off]

`seaborn-on.png:`
[image: seaborn-on]

`seaborn-offagain.png:`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, reset_orig() is a good approach but still it is not producing exactly the original figure in my case. I produced and saved a matplolib figure (two consecutive `plot(xi, yi, '.')` where xi and yi were lists of some hundred elements) from two different ipython notebooks, one using straight matplotlib and another plotting a seaborn figure before resetting to original matplotlib conditions. The color of the dots in the post-seaborn figure was notably less intense\contrasted than in the one with the unaltered matplotlib configuration (like if they had some transparency).

Comment: Maybe it would be best to share some code so others can reproduce that problem?

Comment: I am using the '0.9.0' version and, when I import it, it tells me that "the seaborn.apionly module is deprecated". Still, I need to use `.set_orig` to avoid the effect...

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `matplotlib.style.context` functionality as described in the [style guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html#temporary-styling).

```
#%matplotlib inline #if used in jupyter notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# 1st plot 
with plt.style.context("seaborn-dark"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,2,3], label="First plot (seaborn-dark)")

# 2nd plot 
with plt.style.context("default"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([3,2,1], label="Second plot (matplotlib default)")

#  3rd plot 
with plt.style.context("seaborn-darkgrid"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([2,3,1], label="Third plot (seaborn-darkgrid)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Restore all RC params to original settings (respects custom rc) is allowed by [`seaborn.reset_orig()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.reset_orig.html) function

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25393997/2783943) you can import seaborn with:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
```

And the matplotlib styles will not be modified.