# Controlling the background in Python's matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, figure

I want to have blank background in my figure, however, it seems that the for some reason the default is not. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2]
y=[3,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

This gives me the following figure:

[image]

Why do I get this gridded grey background by default? How would one change the default? And perhaps also how would that differ from setting it only for one figure without changing defaults? Thanks

**Edit**: Apparently, this happened because I imported the `seaborn` module, as the answer suggested. But why does this behavior occur? So if I want to use both `seaborn` and `matplotlib` in one script, I need to keep setting the default background?

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#aesthetics-tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you show in the question isn't actually the matplotlib default style. You may get this because you may have imported some other modules.

To get back the default style use

```
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
```

When e.g. seaborn is imported it sets its own style. This is a very greedy behaviour, but you can of course set another style afterwards

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
```

You may want to look at the [style reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099348/seaborn-configuration-hides-default-matplotlib) may be of interest when no other style is desired. The idea is, to only load the API, without the styles from seaborn

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
```

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you're right on the money. I imported the seaborn module and this caused it. I also edited the question to get some insight about why this is happening.