# importing seaborn changes matplotlib graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use `matplotlib` and `seaborn` to perform some data vizualisation (`heatmap` here). But i realized that the `matplotlib` `heatmap` doesn't look the same at all whether I import `seaborn` or not.

I've launched a `matplotlib` `heatmap` before importing `seaborn`:

[image: Without loading seaborn]

And the same matrix `heatmap` after importing `seaborn`:

[image: After loading seaborn]

I therefore have two questions:

- First why is this happening?
- Second is there a way to counter this fact?

Comment: Use `import seaborn.apionly as sns`, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393936/how-can-i-use-seaborn-without-changing-the-matplotlib-defaults

Comment: Also, as an explanation as to the *why*: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/aesthetics.html

Comment: Thank you guys, those two answers were exactly what I needed :) (sorry for the duplicate btw)