# Seaborn showing values in legend not present in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, legend

I'm generating a scatterplot for a Pandas DataFrame data, containing amongst others the numeric column `'year'` with the unique values

```
array([2010., 2011., 2012., 2013., 2014., 2015., 2016., 2017., 2018.])
```

as shown with `data.year.unique()`.

Displaying the plot like this:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='x', y='y', hue='name', size='year', data=data, palette=sns.color_palette('deep', 7))
```

generates a legend with the groupings for year listed as

[image: 5 size markers with labels 2008 to 2020]

This is misleading, as the plot only contains data from 2010 to 2018.

I've tried passing a tuple (min, max) to the `sns.scatterplot` function as described in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), to no avail.

Changing the data type of the column 'year' to categoric does print the range of the years correctly in the legend, but yields a legend entry for every single year, which is unnecessary and takes up a lot of space.

I've also tried the solution from [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204370/seaborn-showing-values-not-found-in-pandas-columns), but it doesn't change the range of the legend entries.

How can I force seaborn to show the actual range of values in the legend? Alternatively, if it only works by using a categorical column, how can I only show every second entry in the legend?

Comment: [Edit seaborn legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201514/edit-seaborn-legend)　I hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the second approach in the answer worked for me. Still wondering though why this problem occurs in the first place and the scale_order=(min, max) approach doesn't work.